# Does this SE have an approval of using "WordPress" in the title and url from WordPress.org?

Tags: support

From the http://wordpress.org/about/domains/

> For various reasons related to our WordPress trademark, we ask if
>   you’re going to start a site about WordPress or related to it that you
>   not use “WordPress” in the domain name. Try using “wp” instead, or
>   another variation. We’re not lawyers, but very good ones tell us we
>   have to do this to preserve our trademark. Also many users have told
>   us they find it confusing.

So, my question is does this website have some agreement from WordPress.org?

If yes, what are the requirements to be allowed to use the name WordPress in the title/logo and URL?

Answer (score 8):

Read *all* of it. Continued:

> “WordPress” in sub-domains is fine, like wordpress.example.com, we’re just concerned about top-level domains.

Comment: And what about the logo?

Comment: I don't see a WordPress logo on this page or the main site so that's moot

Comment: @Derfder where do you see logo used? If you mean "WordPress" brand itself, it is not considered problematic to use it in general. Think about it - you should be able to say or write it without written permission, or it's not much of a brand. :) Main's footer has usual disclaimer that it's registered trademark.

Comment: @Rarst the logo is here: https://cdn.sstatic.net/wordpressmeta/img/logo.png?v=123 So, I can make a subdomain website called StackExchange Answers using the same or almost same font and hosting like stackexchange.news.cz and it will be OK?

Comment: @Derfder that is not a [WordPress logo](http://wordpress.org/about/logos/). You'll have to take that up with owners of "Stack Exchange" trademark. Owners of WordPress trademark had no issue with "WordPress Answers" (and this name sucks anyway).

Comment: @Derfder If you asking about the use of 'WordPress' in a logo - that's fine - its just top-level domain names they don't want using 'WordPress'.

Comment: @StephenHarris I will write them in a minute and let you know what they think about that. Thanks for now.

Comment: @Derfder The **"The WordPress logotype is set in Mrs. Eaves, licensed by Emigre."** It is not a trademark of WordPress where as the logo is. Problem? Here... no problem.

Answer (score 5):

WordPress Foundation Trademark Usage Policy

We will grant permission to use the WordPress name and logo for projects that meet the following criteria:

- The primary purpose of your project is to promote the spread and
  improvement of the WordPress software.
- Your project is non-commercial in nature (it can make money to cover
  its costs or contribute to non-profit entities, but it cannot be run
  as a for-profit project or business).
- Your project neither promotes nor is associated with entities that
  currently fail to comply with the GPL license under which WordPress
  is distributed.

You can read more here:
http://wordpressfoundation.org/trademark-policy/